# Enter elements to a list and make it become palindrome

Tags: list, scheme, palindrome

I'm new to scheme and stuck on this problem:

Input list = (a b c)
output = (a b c c b a )

Trying to use (reverse) and got the reversed list , but have no idea how to make the list become palindrome.

Comment: Do you know the function `append`? If this is homework, are you allowed to use it?

Comment: Yes, I know it. So should I do something like `(append list (reverse))` ?

Comment: Just found out how to deal with it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Simply append the original list to the reversed list.

```
(define (palindrome lst)
  (append lst (reverse lst)))

(define (reverse lst)
  (define (iter lst res)
    (cond ((null? lst)res)
        (else
         (iter (cdr lst) (cons (car lst) res)))))
    (iter lst '()))
```

---

```
> (palindrome '(1 2 3))

  '(1 2 3 3 2 1)
```

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways to do it.  I write my preferred solution here, but you can find other solutions as well.

```
(define mk/pali
  (lambda (l)
    ((lambda (s) (s s l (lambda (r) (r '()))))
     (lambda (s l* ret)
       (if (null? l*)
           (ret (lambda (x) x))
           (s s (cdr l*)
              (lambda (r0)
                (ret (lambda (y)
                       (cons (car l*)
                             (r0 (cons (car l*) y))))))))))))
```

Because I know that people love to see iterative processes to recursive processes, I eliminated the stacking and I also have a full tail recursive variant.  You can choose that that you like the most.

```
(define mk/pali/tail
  (lambda (l)
    ((lambda (s) (s s l (lambda (r) (r '() (lambda (pali) pali)))))
     (lambda (s l* ret)
       (if (null? l*)
           (ret (lambda (x r) (r x)))
           (s s (cdr l*)
              (lambda (r0)
                (ret (lambda (y r1)
                       (r0 (cons (car l*) y)
                           (lambda (z)
                             (r1 (cons (car l*) z)))))))))))))
```

Here is a test:

```
% mit-scheme < mk-pali.scm
MIT/GNU Scheme running under GNU/Linux

....

1 ]=> (mk/pali '(a b c))
;Value: (a b c c b a)

1 ]=> (mk/pali/tail '(a b c))
;Value: (a b c c b a)
```